# Check whether a list contains a value and if yes return it

Tags: python, list

I want to know how do I know if there exists a specific value in a list and also to return it if exists!

```
a_list = [1, 2, 3, 4]
value = 1
if value in a_list:
    return value
else: return None
```

I know that the above code works, but I want to know whether there is a one-liner way of doing it?

Comment: `return value if value in a_list else None`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
return value if value in a_list else None
```